How to leverage VFP NAT rules for outbound connectivity for overlay networks created by Docker Swarm in Windows server 2022
Description
We are setting up the Docker Swarm Orchestration in the Windows server 2022 (Version 21H2 and OS Build:20348.2340) with MS SQL Server (2022) and Docker Engine version (25.0.3).
We are using .NetCore 8.0, RabbitMQ (For Message Queuing) and docker-compose files.
Each application is deployed as a Microservice.
Issue Description:
We initialized the Swarm (Single Manager node) with VM IP address and it run in Windows server 2022.
We deployed the services using command - docker stack deploy docker-compose.yml <app_name>.We can see the docker service got created with replicated status (1/1) and all the containers are launched successfully (in swarm overlay network). We are able to ping the other container from one container in overlay network.
However we cannot see any outbound connectivity/external traffic from docker swarm containers. It is unable to communicate even to localhost,1433 SQL port or any other ports.
We have tested using docker exec -it <Container_ID> Powershell and Test-NetConnection -ComputerName -Port 1433 command and ping www.google.com also not working.
Even swarm containers are showing UP status , It is not working as expected and seeing failures on SQL connectivity and others .(from docker logs <container_name).
We also found the swarm containers are not using WinNAT/NAT network for External connectivity and each container having it’s own vEthernet container Adapter
Note: Hyper-V is not enabled in Windows server 2022
From MS link, Windows Containers Network, we can see that Swarm containers use VFP (Virtual Filtering Platform) NAT Rules for Outbound connectivity. We are not successful on setting that VFP NAT rules yet and no network access inside the swarm container.
Please help us to resolve this issue
Note: We also have same setup running successfully in Windows server 2016 with SQL server 2016 and Docker Version 20.10.9. In that 2016 server , we can see the swarm containers are using ‘WinNAT’ network/vEthernet NIC adapter for the Outbound connectivity but same step is missing in the 2022 server.
Steps we tried:

Restarted Docker services
Added required firewall connectivity for swarm setup with TCP and UDP ports opened.
Created overlay network for swarm services and use that network for deploying docker swarm.
Added required Firewall for SQL Server- port 1433 and also RabbitMQ.
Non Swarm Windows Container are running fine in same windows 2022 server and it is using NAT network for outbound connectivity
Tried Writing New-NetNat and netsh interface/routing commands to open the external connectivity but it didn't work out.

